How to reproduce a certain style for section-level headers?
I am trying to reproduce that kind of section in a documentclass report on Overleaf, could someone help me please ?

Have a look at the titlesec package

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Overleaf provides lots and lots of templates. Do you remember which template provides the particular style you're interested in?
